# Oracle 10g using collection with sql

Tags: performance, optimization, oracle-10g, query-performance

I have a stored procedure that takes collection of objects. (`TABLE OF MyCustomType`). Inside the procedure I'm trying to join this parameter with real tables.

For example, something like

```
create or replace TYPE MYTYPE AS OBJECT (....);  
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE LIST_OF_MYTYPE AS TABLE OF MYTYPE;

CREATE PROCEDURE FOO(my_table LIST_OF_MYTYPE ,....) AS
  CURSOR cur_read_data IS 
  SELECT a.col1, b.col2, b.col3
  FROM 
  TABLE(FOO.my_table) a
  INNER JOIN existing_table b ON (b.existing_table_id = a.existing_table_id)
  --b.existing_table_id - primary key supported by unique index
  ORDER BY a.existing_table_id
  ;

BEGIN
     FOR record_info in cur_read_data 
     LOOP 
        ......
     END LOOP;
END;
```

It works, but I have a performance issue. Collection parameter passed to the procedure doesn't have many elements; even if it has just one element, execution plan involves full table scan of `existing_table`.

In case of 1 element, changing `INNER JOIN existing_table b ON (b.existing_table_id = a.existing_table_id)` to `INNER JOIN existing_table b ON (b.existing_table_id =FOO.my_table(1).existing_table_id )` makes a huge difference - the query uses "INDEX UNIQUE SCAN" as I expected it for the initial query. I have tried even query hints (ordered, leading) with no results...

Even though the number of elements in collection in my application is between 1 and 5, and it's possible to write 5 different versions of one procedure, I wonder if it's possible to make it work as expected.

For testing, I also did

```
CURSOR cur_read_data IS 
  SELECT a.col1, b.col2, b.col3
  FROM 
   ( 
     SELECT 1 as existing_table_id, 'test 1' as col1 FROM DUAL
      UNION
     SELECT 2 as existing_table_id, 'test 2' as col1 FROM DUAL
      UNION
     SELECT 3 as existing_table_id, 'test 3' as col1 FROM DUAL
   )
  a
  INNER JOIN existing_table b ON (b.existing_table_id = a.existing_table_id)
  --b.existing_table_id - primary key supported by unique index
  ORDER BY a.existing_table_id
```

That way it also works as expected, INDEX_UNIQUE_SCAN, not full scan...

Thanks for your answers.

**UPDATE**
Quite surprisingly, but rewriting it to

```
CURSOR cur_read_data IS 
  WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE(FOO.my_table))
  SELECT a.col1, b.col2, b.col3
  FROM 
  CTE1 a
  INNER JOIN existing_table b ON (b.existing_table_id = a.existing_table_id
  AND b.existing_table_id IN (SELECT existing_table_id FROM CTE1))      
  ORDER BY a.existing_table_id
```

reduced cost about 30 times (1200 original version vs 38 with `WITH`) which is 
 acceptable, but I still have no idea why that helped...

**Another update**

Analyzing `V$SQLSTATS` reveals that for the first version of the cursor it avoids DISK READS at any cost (0), DIRECT WRITES is also 0; using `WITH` somehow changes execution plan resulting in huge improvement in CPU TIME which outweighs increased DISK READS (1)...

Comment: How many rows are you having a problem with? Tablescanning a 1 row table isn't a problem!

Comment: The problem that `existing_table` has more than 500k rows... And for some reason optimizer accesses it prior to tiny collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems with using collections in SQL is that the optimizer isn't able to guess how many elements the collection has.  It defaults to assuming that the collection has a few thousand elements (I want to say 4k elements but I wouldn't wager on that).  If that is roughly 1,000 times more elements than you have in your actual collection, that's will certainly tend to cause the optimizer to make poor choices about the query plan.

The best way to alleviate that problem is to use the `CARDINALITY` hint.

```
SELECT /*+ cardinality(a 4) */ a.col1, b.col2, b.col3
  FROM 
  TABLE(FOO.my_table) a
  INNER JOIN existing_table b ON (b.existing_table_id = a.existing_table_id)
  --b.existing_table_id - primary key supported by unique index
  ORDER BY a.existing_table_id
```

tells the optimizer to assume that the collection aliased to `a` has only 4 elements which should cause it to pick a more appropriate query plan.

Comment: thanks, I'll try. That sounds like a great alternative to my voodoo with `WITH`...

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day. Sorry, I cannot give more than one + :)